# Editing my current excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula currently as =TEXT((B9+B10)/(24*60*60), "m:ss.00")

If I have the values in B9 and B10 as 30.32 and 34.47, which is seconds from my view, it appears as 1:04.79. This is perfect.

BUT if the seconds in B9 and B10 are 25.55 and 26.70, which doesn't add up to a minute, it makes the "m" in the original format unnecessary, so it displays as 0:52.25. Can someone help me amend this formula to remove the "m:" or "0:" when it isn't needed, but still shows when it is necessary?

Answer (score 1):

```
=TEXT((B9+B10)/(24*60*60), IF(B9+B10>=60,"mm:ss.00","ss.00"))
```

Comment: It says it contains an error, any idea where it would be?

Comment: can you give more details?

Comment: It's having an issue with the IF function, specifically the "60" and it is referring back to the IF function. Looks like it's assuming a new IF function starting at the "60"

Comment: the first argument of if function is the criteria. i tried the solution in the excel online and it's working. even with your format, though my separator is not the dot so i had to change it with mine.

Comment: make sure you don't have exceeding parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom number format that changes the format mask when a certain limit (one minute or 0.000694444444444444) is reached.

```
=TEXT((B9+B10)/(24*60*60), "[>0.000694444]m:ss.00;[>0]s.00;_(* \-_);\t\e\x\t")
```

[image]